# iOS offline music player that can import/download from cloud (Dropbox, Google Drive, etc)

Tags: ios, offline, music, google-drive, dropbox

I'm looking for a free (no ads) to less than $3 USD app, that can:

- group music like the native iOS music app (songs, artists, albums, playlists, etc)
- be able to import/download files from the likes Dropbox, Google Drive, etc.

I tried some free apps, and they either have ads or their way to import songs are a bit wonky. I'd like something that can select entire folders or be able to select and download many songs easily.

I was thinking of posting this to Apple, but softwarerecs seemed more appropriate. I hope iOS app recommendations is okay, as I wasn't sure if this was for desktop programs only.

Comment: For those who don't care about "group music like the native iOS music app" you may want to check out VLC for iOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended purchasing cloud beats pro. The reviews were good. Not happy with the complex interface but it does the job somewhat. I'm able add songs to a playlist using songs from Dropbox. I have to additionally download those songs to play them offline.

There was a program called jukebox that was free with no ads, but it kept crashing on my iPhone 6s. Cloud beats worked on more devices although I had to pay $3 for it.